# web2py I need to programmatically update a password field when it's in CRYPT

Tags: web2py

I am designing my Law_firm management app using web2py but for some reason I wanna be able to programmatically update the password in the controller but when I do, it shows up as a normal un-encrypted string which you can be read. so how do I apply the CRYPT validator to my update since I can't login with the new un-encrypted password, here is my code spinet in the controller.

```
record = db.auth_user(confirm.id)
            if record:
                new_password = password_generator(12, UPPER_ALPHANUM)
                record.update_record(password=new_password)
```

Note: password_generator(a,b) is a global function I built some where in one of the models that generates a random password that I have to use in updating the existing password. but it turns out when I check the database instead of getting something like this

```
pbkdf2(1000,20,sha512)$aee0b78b97611f11$56e6595198b550ef26b7d2b5ef6a507c0a3cf858
```

I end up with this

```
D4SO0GSIK98W
```

and I just can't login besides it's not safe so how do I apply the CRYPT validator and I believe that way I can login and also I can be safe, please I don't wanna use the inbuilt reset password because this is different am trying to do something of to accomplish something even way far from that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is transformed via the password field's validator (i.e., its `requires` property), so the simplest way to apply the validator on update is to use the `.validate_and_update` method:

```
db(db.auth_user.id == record.id).validate_and_update(password=new_password)
```

Alternatively, you can apply the validator directly:

```
crypt_validator = db.auth_user.password.requires[0] # The validator is in a list.
hash_password = lambda password: crypt_validator(password)[0]
record.update_record(password=hash_password(new_password))
```

Note, each validator returns a tuple, which includes the (possibly transformed) value and either `None` or an error message. So, the above `hash_password` function extracts the transformed value, which is the first element of the returned tuple.

Comment: Wooow thank you very much i have understood it and they both work perfectly fine thank you again

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept the answer so others know it is correct.

Comment: I would so much like to accept it but I surely have tried the voting and looks like am not qualified to vote yet, so any other way to accept??

Comment: Just click the gray check mark below the voting arrows. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.